Ubuntu remote desktop sharing solution similar to Windows RDP
I have been a user of Windows Remote Desktop for quite long by now. When I replicate the same setup to remotely access my Ubuntu desktop, no matter what solution I try, I find it lacking one way or the other. Specifically, I am looking for the following features:

Dynamic update of host resolution based on client's: The remote host's resolution should adjust seamlessly depending on the client's. It should not matter if I am accessing the remote host from a laptop or a desktop with a widescreen monitor. Note that only scaling it not enough, as it either stretches, or shrinks, or makes scrollbars appear around the remote desktop's window.
Remote host will stay locked and screen turned off during remote access: Otherwise, it is a privacy issue and/or drains power.
Logged in session on remote host can be accessed remotely: The remote desktop solution should not spin up a brand new virtual session. The local session that is logged on to the remote host can be accessed remotely. In other words, if I start working at office, lock the computer, come back home, access it remotely, I should be dropped to the same session and resume work from where I left off.
Access entire desktop, not specific applications: The client machine acts as a thin client. Remote host does the heavy lifting.

Here's the feature matrix of the Ubuntu remote access solutions I tried so far:



Solution
Feature-1
Feature-2
Feature-3
Feature-4




Ubuntu 22.04 Remote Desktop
No
No
Yes
Yes


xrdp
No
Yes
No
Yes


VNC
No
Yes
No
Yes


SSH X-forwarding
No
Yes
No
No



I find it unbelievable that it's 2024 and I cannot find a Linux/Ubuntu-based remote desktop solution that checks all the boxes. Windows RDP does, which is a life saver. Am I missing something? Is there any hack that turns one of these solutions to my dream one? Or, is there something promising that I have not explored yet?
